# java add self signed certificate to keystore programatically

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore, self-signed

I added the self signed certificate using keystore from command prompt.

I found several links which tells how to add certificate to keystore, but they all say to store the certificate locally before running program and do the rest via code. I need to add certificate to keystore dynamically.

How can I add a certificate programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer [this](http://knowledge-oracle.blogspot.com/2009/02/import-private-key-and-certificate-in.html) blog for more help

The JDK JavaDoc for [java.security.KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) is pretty useful too.

If you want to import from external server refer the sun [implementation](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-programatically-extract-a-certificate-from-a-site-and-add-it-to-my-keystore)