# Why do I get "No name matching found" CertificateException?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, https, solaris

As far as I understand in the majority of cases this exception states, that the certificate owner CN (common name) does not match the host name in the url. However in my case they do match, but the exception still raises..

The remote server certificate hierachy is:

1. a self signed certificate with `CN=sms.main.ru`
2. a certificate signed with the first one and `CN=client.sms.main.ru`

My java client is launched under apache-tomcat 6 and tries to connect to `https://client.sms.main.ru/` and the following exception is thrown:

```
No name matching client.sms.main.ru found
```

Both certificates are added to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` via `$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool` as shown in [How do you configure Apache/Tomcat to trust internal Certificate Authorities for server-to-server https requests](https://serverfault.com/questions/200789/how-do-you-configure-apache-tomcat-to-trust-internal-certificate-authorities-for) in the answer by unixtippse.

The Java code is quite trivial:

```
URL url = new URL(strurl);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.connect();
```

What am I missing?

---

Interesting thing is that when I try to access this url with a browser on a Windows PC, it says that the certificate is not trusted, I add it to the browser exception list and it works fine. So it looks like I added these certificates to `cacerts` incorrectly, so that java cannot use them. But I can easily find them by alias or by CN with:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts | less
```

Comment: if it is self-signed then it will not be trusted as the hierarchy will not go all the way up to a TA

Comment: @Scary Wombat But I added them both to the `cacerts`..and marked them there as trusted..Is that not enough? Is this not the way one should do to make a self-signed certificate be trusted?

Comment: You are using the wrong class to access https

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end all I had to do was:

1. Disable hostname verification:

   ```
   // Create all-trusting host name verifier
   HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
       public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
           return true;
       }
   };
   // Install the all-trusting host verifier
   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
   ```
2. Make sure that the default `cacerts` file is used, as while researching I tried to disable ssl certificate verification and used code which can be found in a great number of threads on SO (implementing own `X509TrustManager`), i.e. in [Java: Overriding function to disable SSL certificate check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723415/java-overriding-function-to-disable-ssl-certificate-check). This code replaced default `SSLSocketFactory`, which I needed. So I had to delete all this stuff and use code disabling hostname verification only.

I left `HttpURLConnection`. No need to replace it with `HttpsURLConnection`.

Definitely it would be much better if I managed to avoid disabling hostname verification as well, but I couldn't. Probably something wrong with the certificates..

Comment: didn't downvote, but disabling hostname verification is almost always the wrong thing to do. It shouldn't be recommended as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is previously how I have trusted self signed certs on tomcat

```
static private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory(String jksFile, char[] password) {

    try {
        KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        InputStream in = StaticHttpsClient.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(jksFile);
        try {
            trusted.load(in, password);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier =    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
        socketFactory .setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
        return socketFactory;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

static protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager(String jksFile, char[] password) {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();

    registry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, newSslSocketFactory(jksFile, password)));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(registry);

}
```

Answer (score -5):

Use an `HttpsURLConnection` and `SSLSocketFactory` to perform the SSL handshake.

Comment: How is this supposed to help me?

Comment: Try researching `HttpsURLConnection`. You are using the wrong class to perform SSL, which is how the certificate is presented to the server. Your code does not do anything with a certificate. It will if you use the classes I suggested.

Comment: Thanks for marking it down, not a good way to encourage help!

Comment: Probably it's wrong, but it does work when a real trusted certificate is used by the target server...However, thanks, I'll think it over as well