# Curl -k equivalent in java to supress certification validations and passing username:api key

Tags: java, shell

I am new to java and wanted check the equivalent of -k in java rest client. when i do a curl with -k it works for me on a linux machine. i made client in java .

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class restposts {

// http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/post
public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {

    URL url = new URL("https://test");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("abcd", "defg");

    String input = "{\"status_id\":1,\"comment\":\" Java\"}";

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(input.getBytes());
    os.flush();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();

  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

 }

}

}
```

and it gives me error like

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1902)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
```

I am not sure on this error. Is there a way i can do a suppress this error or is there anything I am missing

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723415/java-overriding-function-to-disable-ssl-certificate-check

Comment: User `HttpsURLConnection` instead of `HttpURLConnection` would be my guess. I assume the connection doesn't really need an type of authentication.