# For SSL connection when actually hostname verification done

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, hostname

For SSL connection when does actually hostname verification done.

Some application servers provide option to disable hostname verification

like in Weblogic it can be disabled at server level

```
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerify
```

We can disable progamitically as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031258/java-ssl-how-to-disable-hostname-verification) by having custom verifier which implments [javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html)

Is there a generic way to disable hostname verification at server level.

Comment: Is this off-topic for StackOverflow? It might belong over at ServerFault...

Comment: If you mean to disable verification for certain hosts in your client, something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723415/java-overriding-function-to-disable-ssl-certificate-check/21103499#21103499 will work.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. Hostname verification is part of HTTPS, not SSL.

Comment: how does Weblogic server allows before it even reaching the application

Comment: Err, because WebLogic is speaking HTTPS?