# Relaxing SSL algorithm constrains programmatically

Tags: java, ssl

## The problem

I'm trying to connect to a local server via a SSL socket. The server uses a SSL certificate that:

1. Is self-signed.
2. Has a MD5withRSA signature (?)

*I am aware of the security implications, but for reasons beyond my control, I cannot change or request changes to this certificate, thus I am forced to work with it - or rather, around it.*

To overcome the above two points, I have created:

1. A `TrustManager` that allows all certificates.
2. An `AlgorithmConstraints` that allows all algorithms.

I end up with the following error:

`Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm: MD5withRSA`

It seems that my approach to relaxing the algorithm constrains is flawed.

**Note**: I am aware that that the `MD5withRSA` algorithm can be allowed via altering the JVM configuration or a commandline parameter, but I need to do this programmatically.

## The code

The `TrustManager` was created as follows:

```
TrustManager[] trustManager = new TrustManager[] { 
    new X509TrustManager() {     
        @Override
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        } 
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted( 
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            } 
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted( 
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    } 
};
```

The `AlgorithmConstraints` was created as follows:

```
AlgorithmConstraints algorithmConstraints = new AlgorithmConstraints() {
    @Override
    public boolean permits(Set<CryptoPrimitive> primitives, String algorithm, AlgorithmParameters parameters) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean permits(Set<CryptoPrimitive> primitives, Key key) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean permits(Set<CryptoPrimitive> primitives, String algorithm, Key key, AlgorithmParameters parameters) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And finally, the socket code is as follows:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); 

sslContext.init(null, trustManager, new java.security.SecureRandom());

SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(server, port);

SSLParameters sslParameters = new SSLParameters();
sslParameters.setAlgorithmConstraints(algorithmConstraints);

sslsocket.setSSLParameters(sslParameters);

sslSocket.startHandshake();
```

Suggestions?

Comment: The correct way would be to include the certificate in your app and use it to initialize a TrustManagerFactory. See first code part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24561444/150978).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The solution

As noted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806709/how-to-bypass-ssl-certificate-checking-in-java/47050878#47050878), one needs to use the `X509ExtendedTrustManager` instead of `X509TrustManager`. This also negates the need for a custom `AlgorithmConstraints` implementation, as I have done in the question.

## The warning

> **For whoever finds/uses this solution:**
>
> Note that bypassing the standard certificate checking exposes the connection (and by extension the application) to a number of security risks, none of which are minor!
>
> Be sure to implement at least *some* additional security checks, like [certificate pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#What_Is_Pinning.3F), or be at least 100% sure that the application is used in a trusted environment!

Answer (score 6):

It seems that certain algorithms are disabled by default in the `JAVA_HOME/lib/jre/security/java.security` properties files, including MD5. In particular, the two security properties `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` and `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms` appear to be critical.

Thanks to dave_thompson_085 for correcting my confusion about system properties and security properties. By simply using the [`Security.setProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method I was able to connect to an SSL server using a certificate signed with MD5WithRSA. I copies the values of the two security properties from the `JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security` file and removed MD5 from the disabled algorithms, then called `Security.setProperty()` with the modified list. On my JDK the values of these properties were:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
    EC keySize < 224, DES40_CBC, RC4_40, 3DES_EDE_CBC

jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, \
    RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224
```

I edited out the MD5 restrictions and executed the following two lines at the beginning of the program before any crypto is used:

```
Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "SSLv3, RC4, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, DES40_CBC, RC4_40, 3DES_EDE_CBC");
Security.setProperty("jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms", "MD2, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224");
```

Note that, of course, this leaves you exposed to MD5 vulnerabilities. You only want to be exposed to them for the one self-signed certificate, but now you have to do all the work of disallowing MD5 everywhere else in TLS by yourself.

Comment: `-D` sets a system property but the items in the `java.security` file are _security_ properties. You _can_ set them in code by calling `Security.setProperty()` but you have to do it at startup (before the related classes are loaded and initialized) and it applies to everything in the JVM.

Comment: I did a quick test and indeed it connects - or at least, no error occurs when doing the `sslSocket.startHandshake();` call. However, I am looking for a way to relax the constrains for this connection only, not for the entire JVM. Still, your answer has its merits. Thanks!