# Java disable Certificate validation still getting PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, tls1.2

I disabled the TLS and SSL server certificate validation using the code below, but still I get 'PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target'.
What is wrong? The certificate on server is from Let's encrypt.

The code is from other posts in StackOverflow, for example: [How to bypass ssl certificate checking in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806709/how-to-bypass-ssl-certificate-checking-in-java)

```
 HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);

                SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)  {}
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return new X509Certificate[0]; }}}, new SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory( context.getSocketFactory());


                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806709/how-to-bypass-ssl-certificate-checking-in-java
                final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                        new X509ExtendedTrustManager() {
                            @Override
                            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] xcs, String string, Socket socket) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] xcs, String string, Socket socket) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] xcs, String string, SSLEngine ssle) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] xcs, String string, SSLEngine ssle) {
                            }

                        }
                };

                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
                installed = true;
```

Here is the exception full text.

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
  at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
  at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.executeHandshake(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:303)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:251)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:181)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:447)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:162)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:172)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:142)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:152)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:123)
  at com.wisecoders.dbs.dialogs.system.j.a(ReportBugTask.java:56)
  at com.wisecoders.dbs.dialogs.system.j.call(ReportBugTask.java:27)
```

Comment: `getAcceptedIssuers()` isn't allowed to return `null`, so the code is junk, but the fact is that you *haven't* disabled certificate checking at all: otherwise you could not have got this error. Reexamine your assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

You have almost configured it correctly, however it is slightly off. What you need to do is create an URL object from the url itself and open the connection, cast it to a HttpsUrlConnection and pass the ssl configuration to it. An example snippet would be:

```java
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedTrustManager;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UnsafeTrustManager unsafeTrustManager = new UnsafeTrustManager();
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = (hostname, sslSession) -> true;

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{unsafeTrustManager}, null);

        URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println(responseCode);
    }

    private static class UnsafeTrustManager extends X509ExtendedTrustManager {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, Socket socket) {}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, Socket socket) {}
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine) {}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine) {}
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
    }

}
```

The above example is for httpsurlconnection, however in your stacktrace I see Apache http client 5, which needs to be configured differently, see below for an example:

```java
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.socket.LayeredConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedTrustManager;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UnsafeTrustManager unsafeTrustManager = new UnsafeTrustManager();
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = (hostname, sslSession) -> true;

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{unsafeTrustManager}, null);

        LayeredConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);
        var connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
                .build();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .build();
    }

    private static class UnsafeTrustManager extends X509ExtendedTrustManager {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, Socket socket) {}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, Socket socket) {}
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine) {}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine) {}
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
    }

}
```

So I think you need the second option, however it is up to you whichever you want to use. I would not recommend to disable the security validations. It is better to add the server certificate to a truststore file and use that to create a trustmanager. In that way your client will work with the configured trusted certificate and fail while calling other servers and that is exactly what you want, but it is up to you what you prefer. Can you give the code snippet above a try and share your results here?