# HTTPS vs HTTP in java

Tags: java

We got an wsdl from a website and we generated the java code with Axis2. Works perfect but the **site is HTTPS and has the SSL certificatite turned off**.

When I make a request I get

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The admin from the site told me to disable SSL

I can't seem to find a solution for this.

What do I need to call before the request to disable this?

Comment: Hi. Since the site is https and requires a certificate. You need to add the certificate to your `jre/lib/security/cacerts`. One way is to click on the lock icon on your url and then download the certificate from there.

Comment: **THE SITE HAS CERTIFICATE TURNED OFF. NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID** when I visit the site

Comment: Please share what you have tried. Did you refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723415/java-overriding-function-to-disable-ssl-certificate-check ?

Comment: @Vebbie I just did that. I get the same error

Comment: Add the code you have so far to the question so someone can help you.

Comment: Check this, maybe can help you- https://superuser.com/a/1083768